# Рекурсия, рекурсивный процесс, итеративный процесс

Tags: javascript, функциональное-программирование

1. Может ли рекурсия быть реализована с помощью рекурсивного или итеративного процесса?
2. Итерация и цикл это одно и тоже? 
   [Источник](https://ru.hexlet.io/blog/posts/recursive)

Что можно почитать о рекурсии, итерации подробнее?

Comment: 1. В общем случае рекурсия — это (сюрприз!) рекурсивный процесс; однако *хвостовую рекурсию* можно развернуть в цикл, то есть представить в виде итеративного процесса. 2. Итерация — это единичный проход по циклу (т. е. его часть).

Comment: Мне неизвестны общепринятые определения "итеративного процесса" и "рекурсивного процесса". Это явно чей-то птичий язык. Чтобы ответить на этот вопрос, потребуются конкретные определения. И не задавайте несколько несвязанных вопросов в одном.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос ссылку на источник, по которому, как ожидается, вы должны ответить на этот вопрос. А лучше сами определения. Если это хекслет, то там имеет место ошибка перевода: там речь о **линейно**-рекурсивном процессе. А имеющийся сейчас ответ эту ошибку тоже содержит и фактически неверен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Да, рекурсия может встречаться как в рекурсивном, так и в итеративном процессе.

Допустим нам нужно найти 2 в 5ой степени.

---

**Итеративный подход:**

```js
console.log(pow(2, 5));

function pow(base, exponent) {
  const iter = (current, exp) => {
    if(exp > 1) return iter(current * base, exp - 1);
    
    return current;
  }

  return iter(base, exponent);
}
```

На каждой итерации происходит подсчет текущего значения которое передается в новый вызов функции. Рекурсивный вызов функцией самой себя в наличии.

```
2 * 2 = 4   // -> передали
4 * 2 = 8   // -> передали
8 * 2 = 16  // -> передали
16 * 2 = 32 // -> завершаем, выводим значение
```

---

**Рекурсивный подход:**

```js
console.log(pow(2, 5));

function pow(base, exponent) {
  if(exponent > 1) return base * pow(base, exponent - 1);
  
  return base;
}
```

На каждой итерации получаем значение выполнения функции домноженное на предыдущий вызов. Рекурсивный вызов функцией самой себя в наличии.

```
2 * func               // -> состояние сохраняется
2 * 2 * func           // -> состояние сохраняется
2 * 2 * 2 * func       // -> состояние сохраняется
2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 = 32 // -> функция возвращает значение, происходит подсчет, рекурсивный вызов прекращается
```

---

2) Нет, итерация - это шаг цикла.

Comment: Ваш "итеративный подход" - ни разу не итеративный, это цикл, который замаскирован под рекурсию, которая перекорежена так чтобы транслятор сумел заменить ее на цикл...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, вполне возможно, вы можете внести свои правки или дать свой ответ, мы тут как раз за тем, что бы делиться опытом и собирать базу знаний.

Comment: *Я предпочитаю не отвечать на вопрос раньше чем я пойму в чем он заключается...*

Comment: Именно, давайте делиться опытом и собирать базу знаний, а не распространять чьи-то найденные в гугле ошибки и заблуждения. Нет, не любая рекурсия может быть реализована итеративно. Попробуйте итеративно реализовать быструю сортировку (Хоара).

Comment: @D-side, так вроде вопрос и не стоял "любая или нет", вопрос был именно в том, может ли в принципе.

Comment: В таком случае "рекурсия может быть реализована" это излишне общее утверждение для вашего ответа. Выше пример, когда не может. Вашему утверждению он противоречит.

Comment: @D-side, имеет место сложная проблема толкования ...